# How to add uiview and make it the self view center using autolayout and without setting frame or center property

Tags: objective-c, autolayout

How to add uiview and make it the self view center using autolayout and without setting frame or center property.

I know that we can set like this

```
view.center = window.center;
```

or

```
view.center = self.view.center;
```

but i want to set to the center of the view to self view center using autolayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be adding 4 constraints to your view then:

- One for "center horizontally"
- One for "center vertically"
- One to set its height to a certain value
- One to set its width to a certain value

You can create constraints in code like this, and add them to your view:

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX 
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                                toItem:tab
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX 
                            multiplier:1.0 
                              constant:0];
```

Comment: what is label? what is tab in this?

Comment: They're just placeholders as an example. You should replace them with your actual views. In your case, label is the view that you're trying to center and tab is the window or your view controller's view.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with storyboard you don't need to write any code. **Use Size Inspector** and remove all the line in **Autosizing** part.

[image]

Comment: if i want autolayout and checked in xib inspector properties then i will not find autosizing properties